# NSResponder accepts events when acceptsFirstResponder is false?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Why are the methods moveLeft() and moveRight() being called, I have turned off the first responder ability for the window controller? I haven't added any code in elsewhere, so I'm obviously missing something somewhere...

In the end I do want to accept events, but if I 'enable' them here and deal with overriding keyEvent(), it causes it to be handled twice and a choice being made twice.

```
import Cocoa

enum UserChoice {
    case Left, Right
}

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }

    override var windowNibName: String? {
        return "MainWindowController"
    }

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func moveLeft(sender: AnyObject?) {
        chooseImage(UserChoice.Left)
    }

    override func moveRight(sender: AnyObject?) {
        chooseImage(UserChoice.Right)
    }

    func chooseImage(choice: UserChoice) {
        print("choice made")
    }

}
```

The only other file I have is AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var mainWindowController: MainWindowController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) {
        mainWindowController = MainWindowController()
        mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
    }

}
```

Any comments on my code are welcome too, I'm new to Swift/Cocoa so...

Answer (score 3):

When your controller refuses to be first responder, it's still a responder, just not the first one.  Another responder such as the window or a view within it can choose to pass the buck back up the responder chain.

I'm not clear on why you implemented `moveLeft` and `moveRight` if you don't want to handle them.